# Is this a reasonable setup for a Firebase backend for a group chat app?

Tags: trigger, nosql, firebase

This is my idea so far:

**Firestore will store group info that will never/rarely change, such as groupID, groupName, groupAdmin:**

1. Lock down Firestore such that a user can only read from a collection that they are the "owner of", i.e. where that collection is a sub-collection in their own user document:

   ```
   match /users/{uid}/groups/{groupID} { 
       allow read, write, delete: if isOwner(uid);
   }

   function isOwner(uid) {

     return request.auth.uid == uid

   }
   ```
2. When a user creates a group, it creates a record for it in their `users/{uid}/groups` collection.
3. Then, a cloud function triggers that creates a record for this group in another collection called `mainGroups` that **end users cannot read or write to**.
4. Now, when the user adds a member to this group, this group member is also added to the `mainGroups` record via another trigger. Basically, anything that the admin does to their own group is replicated to the record in `mainGroups`.
5. Now let's say that the member accepts the group requests. A trigger then fires to create a group record in the member's `users/{uid}/groups`. And now going forward, any changes to the record in `mainGroups` will be replicated to the member's record in `users/{uid}/groups`.

**Realtime Database will store information that can change frequently, such as groupSlogan, groupMembers, and groupChats:**

1. Lock down RTDB to only allow a user to read/write to a node if they are authenticated and only allow them to read the groupMembers list and the groupChats list if their `auth.id` exists in the list of groupMembers.
2. When a record in `mainGroups` is created, a trigger will fire that will create the appropriate nodes for that group in RTDB.
3. If an admin deletes their group, a trigger will fire that will delete the record in `mainGroups`. Then, another trigger will fire that will delete the records in each member's personal groups collection and also delete the group's node in RTDB.

The basic idea I've found is to use Firestore for data that will not change much and use RTDB for data that will change frequently. It's easy to see what to do for a user's personal information, but for the group chat it's more complicated because it is a "gathering place" where many people will read and write to. And top of that, I want to keep the security rules simple, so I coded it to only consider 1 person as the owner for each sub-collection under their user document.

Does this all seem reasonable? What critiques can be made about this setup? Or is there a recommended way to set up the Firebase backend for a group chat app?